gSOAP ns1__** is missing form soapstub.h (Upgrade from 2.7.12 to 2.8.135)
I am planning to upgrade gSOAP from 2.7.12 to 2.8.135. While using gSOAP 2.8.135, I noticed that generated soapStub.h does not contain prefix ns1__ in the generated structs.
For example, on gSOAP 2.7.12 the struct name was ns1__parameter. With gSOAP 2.8.135, it is generated as parameter. I don't want to change existing implementation where ns1__parameter is consumed.
Any pointers to generate soapStub.h with ns1__ prefix with gSOAP 2.8.135
Thanks.
